# Excel formula to change a number from + to – when word “Db” is next cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a many long statements converted from text, the credits and debits all are in same column as plain positive amounts, to distinguish the credits to debits the cell next to the amounts shows the word “Db” or “Cr”. I need a formula that convert all the amounts next to the cell with the word “Db” into a negative (i.e. -58.00) without having to manually put a minus (-) in the many hundreds

Answer (score 1):

Add a third column and put this in that column:

```
=IF(B1="Db";-A1;A1)
```

With `A1` being your value and `B1` being the column with "Db" or "Cr". Then copy this formula till as far as you need it.

See example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj6BGz6LYoJndGZLbmNOQTFxQXRnR1I4cmN6RFY0Snc)